# How do you add multiple decimal points to a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table that contains 10-digit hts codes (0000.00.0000). Some of the values do not have the full stop points (0000000000). How can I add the full stop points to all the rows that do not have them?

Edit
The column type is VARCHAR
I want to update all rows where full stop is not present.

Comment: what data type are you using?

Comment: Should we assume that the data type of this column is VARCHAR or TEXT?

Comment: Do you want to add the full stops to the result query or UPDATE that actual rows where there is a problem

Comment: _Small Point_ If there is one full stop it might be considered a decimal point, if there are 2 full stops it could not possibly be a decimal point as like swordsmen ___there can be only one___

Comment: Remove all non-digit chars then add points into needed places. But I'd recommend to store your codes as numbers (and in integer-type column), and add points while retirieving.

Comment: I want to update the rows permanently to include the full stops. It is Varchar type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the full stops from all these columns using `REPLACE()` as part of the update, then you can apply some simple logic using a `CONCAT()` `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` and `SUBSTRING()`
to change the simple `0000000000` into `0000.00.0000` like this, rather than trying to identify only the columns without the dots

```
UPDATE table 
    set column = CONCAT( 
                    LEFT(REPLACE(column, '.', ''),4), 
                    '.' , 
                    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(column, '.', ''),5,2), 
                    '.', 
                    RIGHT(REPLACE(column, '.', ''),4)
                );
```

Test it using a select so you do no damage

```
SELECT some_identifying_column, 
        CONCAT( 
                LEFT(REPLACE(column, '.', ''),4), 
                '.' , 
                SUBSTRING(REPLACE(column, '.', ''),5,2), 
                '.', 
                RIGHT(REPLACE(column, '.', ''),4)
            ) as justtesting;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `insert` comes to mind. As others already mentioned, it's a good idea to remove the full stops before inserting them in the 5th and 8th position in the string

```
select *, insert(insert(replace(hts,'.',''),5,0,'.'),8,0,'.')
from t;
```